# How to select Element inside form via Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

I can't find a way to select span `editItem:hello` via Jsoup.

```
<body>
<form id="editItem" name="editItem" method="post" action="/Project/gub.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="editItem" value="editItem" />
<span id="editItem:hello">Hello Jsoup-World!</span>
</form>
</body>
```

I tried a lot of good looking possibilites from [Jsoup Selector Syntax Doc](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) but it never worked out.
Changing the HTML is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try specifying the selector as:

```
span[id=editItem:hello]
```

You can see it working at http://try.jsoup.org/~lXJJZ0FNgs8E1uCSIzGW6PnCqmI.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the CSS-Selector will not work when there is a colon in the id. But you can use
`Document.getElementById(String id)`